# Plotly sunburst coloring

Tags: r, colors, plotly, r-plotly, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to color a [sunburst](/questions/tagged/sunburst) by parent and then by level so that parent1 and parent2 are red and blue and then they gradient outwards by level.

I seem to be close using layout with `sunburstcolorway` but it doesn't quite color by level. Currently my input for colorway is a list of hex codes that are specified for each observation.

If there is a way to specify color for each individual section that would be ideal. I can't seem to figure it out, I'm very new to this

```
library(plotly)
clin2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ids = c("MGH","CU","MGH - WT",
          "CU - WT","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM","MGH - G2032R",
          "MGH - S1986F","MGH - D2033N","CU - L1951R/L2026M"),
  labels = c("Gainor<br>et al. 2017",
             "McCoach<br>et al. 2018","ROS1<br>Extrinsic",
             "ROS1<br>Extrinsic","ROS1<br>Intrinsic","ROS<br>Intrinsic","G2032R",
             "S1986F","D2033N","L1951R/<br>L2026M"),
  parents = c(NA,NA,"MGH","CU","MGH",
              "CU","MGH - KDM","MGH - KDM","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM"),
  values = c(17L, 12L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  colors = c("#3182bd", "#e6550d", "#9ecae1", "#fdae6b", "#9ecae1",
             "#fdae6b", "#deebf7", "#deebf7", "#deebf7", "#fee6ce")
)

clin2_plot <- plot_ly(clin2, ids = ~ids, labels = ~labels, parents = ~parents, 
                      values = ~values, type = 'sunburst', branchvalues = 'total'
) %>% layout(sunburstcolorway = clin2$colors)

clin2_plot
```

[image: This is the current output]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, can you please add `clin2`? Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: Just added some photos for clin2 and the current output of the code

Comment: Great. But the `clin2` in the right format please. See previous comment to properly format & paste your data here. Someone here can reproduce your problem then.

Comment: Okay I added the csv as a code block. Thank you for the instruction, it's helpful

Comment: Unfortunately, the data you've provided is not producing any output in my system!

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited your code to make it reproducible. To me it seems to be working fine. I added a black trace - Please check the following:

```
library(plotly)

clin2 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
  ids = c("MGH","CU","MGH - WT",
          "CU - WT","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM","MGH - G2032R",
          "MGH - S1986F","MGH - D2033N","CU - L1951R/L2026M"),
  labels = c("Gainor<br>et al. 2017",
             "McCoach<br>et al. 2018","ROS1<br>Extrinsic",
             "ROS1<br>Extrinsic","ROS1<br>Intrinsic","ROS<br>Intrinsic","G2032R",
             "S1986F","D2033N","L1951R/<br>L2026M"),
  parents = c(NA,NA,"MGH","CU","MGH",
              "CU","MGH - KDM","MGH - KDM","MGH - KDM","CU - KDM"),
  values = c(17L, 12L, 8L, 11L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
  colors = c("#111111", "#e6550d", "#9ecae1", "#fdae6b", "#9ecae1",
             "#fdae6b", "#deebf7", "#deebf7", "#deebf7", "#fee6ce")
)

clin2_plot <- plot_ly(clin2, ids = ~ids, labels = ~labels, parents = ~parents, 
                      values = ~values, type = 'sunburst', branchvalues = 'total'
) %>% layout(colorway = ~colors)

clin2_plot
```

[image: Result]