# Change colors of sunburst plot with R plot_ly

Tags: r, plotly, sunburst-diagram

I used plot_ly to visualize my data as sunburst as done before with Adobe Illustrator, however failed to colour the segments likewise.

Here is the code (colour codes are random):

```
library(plotly)
tab <- data.frame(
  labels = c("Total", "Planerlöse", "Abgeltung", "Bund", "Kanton Thurgau", "Kanton Thurgau Netto", "Gemeinden" ),
  parents = c("", "Total", "Total", "Abgeltung", "Abgeltung", "Kanton Thurgau", "Kanton Thurgau"),
  values = c(100, 46,54, 23.76, 30.24, 20.26, 9.97),
  colors=c("#f28f1c", "#fef4e8", "#2771b0", "#e9f1f7",
           "#b5b5b5", "#787878", "#333333"),
  type = 'sunburst',
  branchvalues = 'total'
)

fig <- plot_ly(tab, labels = ~labels, parents = ~parents, 
                      values = ~values, colors=colors, type = 'sunburst', branchvalues = 'total'
)

fig
```

And here the original plot I'd like to replicate:
[image]

Thanks for any advise and help!

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61130745/plotly-sunburst-coloring). Have you tried this solution, `p |> layout(colorway = ~colors)` and found it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks, see my comment above, this does not solve the question of coloring each segment in a different color, I've already tried this...any other idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key here is to realise that, somewhat surprisingly, the arcs in a sunburst plot are considered to be markers in the same way as a point in a scatter plot. This means we can style them in the way described in the `plotly` [marker style docs](https://plotly.com/r/marker-style/). For example:

```r
# Define marker
marker <- list(
    colors = ~colors,
    line = list(
        color = "black",
        width = 2
    )
)

plot_ly(
    tab,
    labels = ~labels,
    parents = ~parents,
    values = ~values,
    type = "sunburst",
    branchvalues = "total",
    marker = marker # pass the marker here
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `layout` using [`colorway`](https://plotly.com/r/colorway/) to add the colors to your sunburst plot like this:

```r
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

fig <- plot_ly(tab, labels = ~labels, parents = ~parents, 
               values = ~values, type = 'sunburst', branchvalues = 'total'
) %>% layout(colorway = ~colors)

fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I tried that. But how do I need to change the color list so that each segment appears in a different color?